# Infinispan Version for Spring Boot 2.4.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, openshift, infinispan

which version of infinispan should i use for spring boot version 2.4.3 ?

My pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>



<dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-spring-boot-starter-remote</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The deploy fail for this problem:

```
datagrid-app-hotrod.1389-dev.svc.cluster.local/172.30.145.147:11333] due to transport error 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: FaultTolerantPingOperation{bilancio-aggiustamento, flags=0, connection=datagrid-app-hotrod.1389-dev.svc.cluster.local/172.30.145.147:11333} timed out after 60000 ms
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.operations.HotRodOperation.run(HotRodOperation.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*
```

Thanks,
Giuseppe.

Comment: it looks like the server is not running in 172.30.145.147:11333. can you double-check if the ISPN server is running at that IP&PORT?

Comment: yes, the server 172.30.145.147:11333. is up&running. The project with the version spring boot 2.1.X and infinispan 2.1.7.Fina work. Not work with the version 2.4.3 spring boot

Answer (score 0):

This [pull request](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/pull/9143) was merged a couple of days ago. The next release should work with Spring Boot 2.4.3